# Can a MozBackup backup file be converted into a FEBE file?

Tags: firefox, passwords, save, backup, bookmarks

I recently switched over to Ubuntu and removed Windows 7. I backed up my Firefox stuff using MozBackup, which appearently does not work on Linux. I tried wine and still not working.

Now regarding the question, I would like to know if there is any chance to "convert" a MozBackup file into a FEBE backup file.

Answer (score 0):

I know that the question is old and might not be helpful for the op, but for the others: MozBackup just creates a zip archive containing your original profile folder. So, you can open the .pcv file it creates as an archive (eventually change it's extension from .pcv to .zip before), and copy it's content to the profile folder of the new installation.

In Ubuntu, I think this is something like `~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/` .

A recommended (and detailed) way to migrate to Linux can be found at http://kb.mozillazine.org/Moving_from_Windows_to_Linux .